How to prevent a query from running in the Entity Framework Core
I am using Entity Framework Core 7 in my project. In some scenarios in my code, EF Core generates an empty query, like this "", and I get the following error:

(ERROR) OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync():
System.InvalidOperationException: OracleCommand.CommandText is invalid
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.DoPreExecuteProcessing(OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Boolean bXmlQuerySave)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Is there a way to prevent the execution of a query when it is equal to "" (an empty string)?
I used an interceptor, but it didn't work.
public class QueriesInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override DbCommand CommandCreated(CommandEndEventData eventData, DbCommand result)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.CommandText) ? result : base.CommandCreated(eventData, result);
    }

    public override DbCommand CommandInitialized(CommandEndEventData eventData, DbCommand result)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.CommandText) ? result : base.CommandInitialized(eventData, result);
    }
}


Have you tried to find root of the problem? I don't remember that EF Core can generate such empty query.

I would be focusing on "why does my code try and execute an empty string?"  Linq against DbSets will not generate empty SQL statements. If your code is building SQL to execute directly, this isn't the way EF is meant to be utilized except for truly exceptional scenarios, and in those cases if your code is conditionally building SQL then your code should be only feeding that SQL for EF to execute if there is actually something to execute.
